# PHP Twitter API Can't grab georss:point and store as variable?

Tags: php, api, twitter, geolocation

I am new to API's like today new. I have learned how to simply call the twitter api xml data and pull certain things off from a post. My problem though is I can't seem to figure out how to pull off the Geo or Coordinates in the Twitter API and display it or store it as a variable.

```
<html>
<?php
$xmldata = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/allencoded.xml';
$open = fopen($xmldata, 'r');
$content = stream_get_contents($open);
fclose($open);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
?>
<?php 
$geo = $xml->status[0]->coordinates->georss:point; //<---PROBLEM POINT!!!!
?>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="<? echo $xml->status[0]->user->profile_image_url; ?>" /></td>
<td>
<? echo $xml->status[0]->text; ?> at <? echo $xml->status[0]->created_at; ?> by <? echo $xml->status[0]->user->name; ?> 
</td>
<td>
GEO IS AT:<? echo $geo; ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run code I get:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\inetpub\vhosts\allencoded.com\httpdocs\twitter.php on line 11

When I remove the code for line 11 everything works though.

Comment: georss is a namespace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517887/php-parsing-a-georss-namespace-with-simplexml and http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/688#Heading3 should help.

Comment: hey there, just wanted to warn you that you're very close to be banned from asking questions here on SO. don't delete questions with answers and start answering yourself to dodge the oncoming ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think PHP parsed the XML verbatim. While `georss:point` is a valid node in the XML tree, that syntax means something else to PHP. Try doing a `print_r()` on  the `$xml->status[0]->coordinates` value and see what it says the properties are.

Comment: Yep. Looks like you have to make another call to the URL supplied in the Place property, which gets you a JSON object to decode. Fun times...

Comment: `print_r()` (and `var_dump()`) on SimpleXMLElement objects only reports on non-namespaced items. However they are available to access!

Comment: You'll need to use `$xml->status[0]->children("georss", TRUE)` to access them as others have pointed out, but thats the code that worked for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with namespaced elements (like `namespace_name:element_name`), you need to tell SimpleXML to load the elements of that namespace (default is to load elements without a namespace). For that, you use `SimpleXMLElement::children()` ([docs](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children)).

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/allencoded.xml');
$geo = (string) $xml->status->geo->children('georss', true)->point;
echo $geo;
```

The first chunk of the key line there `$xml->status->geo` gets the first `geo` element of the first status element. Then we ask for the children that belong to the `georss` namespace (so, any `georss:…` elements), followed by specifying that we want the (first, only) `point`.