# How to extract a georss:point tag from an xml feed using php

Tags: xml, rss, simplexml

I have seen many links on this site. One of them were very close:
[parsing a georss namespace with simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517887/php-parsing-a-georss-namespace-with-simplexml?rq=1)

For my purpose, I had the code edited like this:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Testing</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    $file = "http://www.ubalert.com/alerts.rss";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);  
    $loc = $xml->channel->entry;  
    foreach ($loc->children('http://www.georss.org/georss') as $geo)
 { 
        echo $geo;
    } 
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to extract the georss:point tag values from the given rss feed. I have tried a lot but failed. Running the above code gives fatal error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpproj\Test2.php on line 10

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but maybe this will help someone looking to parse GeoRss Feeds or any xml that uses namespaces.

```
$url = 'http://www.ubalert.com/alerts.rss';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 
$namespaces = $xml;
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    //Use Namespace
    $geo = $entry->children($namespaces['georss']); 
    echo $geo->point;
    echo "\n";
}
```